# Changing url to friendly url php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom folder with number of php files. i want to create a friendly URL by removing .php from the URL.So i have created the .htaccess file in the custom folder where all the .php files located and written the below code but its is not working.

My URL is: `magento/cl/unilever.php`

Expected URL: `magento/cl/unilever`

.htaccess contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unilever $ unilver.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to rewrite just single directory, try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: i have copied this code to .htaccess ,its not working

Comment: I've tested it, and it's working. Does `mod_rewrite` is enabled? Or it's just rewrite rules not working?

Comment: Maybe because another `.htaccess` file is overriding, check if there are another redirections in parent directories, if so we'd do it differently

Comment: There is no redirections in the parent directory.

Comment: So does it throws any error? or just it does nothing?

Comment: its just throwing not found error when i try to access

Comment: OK please see this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509099/htaccess-no-extension-required if anyway you can't succeed you can skype me @garchagudashvili without '@'