# clean url using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

ive seen things like

```
<?php
 if(is_array($_GET)) { 
    $page = isset($_GET['p'])?strtolower(urlencode($_GET['p'])):'index.php'; 
    $page = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/','',$page); 
//  echo '['.$page.']'; 
} 
else $page = ''; 
if(!file_exists($page.'.php')) require("index.php"); 
else require(_path_.$page.'.php');
```

} 
    ?>

But i dont really get how this works entirely.

Basically I want to do something with php and htaccess i believe i will know, example; domain.com/page/about would go to domain.com/pages/about.php and output the contents? i know ive seen this somewhere but i forget what its called! I've been searching forever now!

Im not the best at code and need a bit help to do, please.

Comment: the above script is quite easy to understand. What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `mod_rewrite`. See [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for a comprehensive explanation. Tuts+ also has a nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708).

You essentially want to get the the page as a token and pass that to this script as a GET parameter, which your script will evaluate.

**If you don't need the full functionality of `mod_rewrite` and you're just looking to drop the PHP extension, then this question is more relevant: [.htaccess; no extension required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509099/htaccess-no-extension-required)**